# Querying related OneToMany entities using Criteria API produces an extra join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA entities with an unidirectional OneToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

If I use the findAll() method to get all Users, then JPA+Hibernate execute the N+1 queries to get all notes of every User. The SQL executed is as follows:

```
select
    n1_0.user_id,
    n1_1.id,
    n1_1.name 
from
    user_notes n1_0 
join
    note n1_1 
        on n1_1.id=n1_0.notes_id 
where
    n1_0.user_id=?
```

I would like to do the same query using Criteria API but I'm not able to do it in the same way because a query with an extra join is executed.

I tried the following code:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Note> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Note.class);

Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
Join<User, Note> noteJoin = userRoot.join("notes");

criteriaQuery.select(noteJoin).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("id"), userId));

TypedQuery<Note> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getResultList();
```

But this query with an extra join is executed:

```
select
    n1_1.id,
    n1_1.name 
from
    user u1_0 
join
    (user_notes n1_0 
join
    note n1_1 
        on n1_1.id=n1_0.notes_id) 
            on u1_0.id=n1_0.user_id 
    where
        u1_0.id=n1_0.notes_id
```

How can I do with Criteria API the same query that's done with N+1 findAll() to get all Notes from a given user without incurring in extra join?

Comment: what table is user_notes ? In OneToMany you don't need such table.